# SQL server 2005 query not running

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Before posting this question, I have tried so many things but that was not helpful for me.
I want to rename  the column of table at sql server 2005, following query I have run at sql server2005:

> 1) ALTER TABLE Details RENAME COLUMN
>   AccountID TO UID; but it gives me the
>   error: Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'COLUMN'.
>
> 2)I have added one new column in the
>   table by query:  ALTER TABLE Details
>   ADD BID uniqueidentifier;   and then I
>   want to set the coulmn property to not
>   null .

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance
AS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sp_Rename 'TableName.Column', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'`.

In order to do your second part of the question, you'll need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
        ADD myColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT 'some default value'
```

If you don't want to specify a default value, you'll have to first create the column with `NULL`.  Once the column is created, you can then populate with your desired values and then re-alter the column to `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Instead of using `ALTER TABLE`, why not use [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238878%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)?  For example:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Details.[AccountID]', 'title', 'UID'
```

2)  You can use `ALTER TABLE Details ALTER COLUMN BID NOT NULL`, but you'll probably want to specify a default value for it also, if the table already has data in it.